# PHP/MYSQL query help needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This should be straightforward.
I have three tables (relevant columns shown).

**users** :   **ID,USERNAME,PWD**

**shops**:    **ID,MANAGER_ID** (referencing a USER_ID)**,NETWORK_ID**

**networks** : **ID,ADMIN_ID** (referencing a USER_ID)

All I need to do, is upon login, check USERNAME and PWD against the ID and to be able to tell if the user that just logged on, is simply in shops table as a manager, or a network admin, or both.

Can this be done with one single SELECT with PHP ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    users.id AS user_id,
    shops.id AS shop_id,
    networks.id AS network_id

FROM users

LEFT OUTER JOIN shops
ON shops.manager_id = users.id

LEFT OUTER JOIN networks
ON networks.manager_id = users.id

WHERE users.username = ?
  AND users.pwd = ?

LIMIT 1
```

When this query returns, `shop_id` will be non-null if the user is referenced from the shops table, and the same goes for `network_id`.

Note that if the user is referenced from the shops or networks table more than once, this query will only produce one row; I assume from your question that you don't care which shop/network the user is associated with, you only want to check for such an association.

Alternatively, this query would work too:

```
SELECT
    users.id AS user_id,

    EXISTS (SELECT shops.id
            FROM shops
            WHERE shops.manager_id = users.id)
        AS has_shop,

    EXISTS (SELECT networks.id
            FROM networks
            WHERE networks.admin_id = users.id)
        AS has_network

FROM users

WHERE users.username = ?
  AND users.pwd = ?
```

One of the queries might be faster than the other depending on what indexes you have set up on the tables, as well as your MySQL version.  Consider running them both through `EXPLAIN` if performance is an issue.

Comment: I use MYSQL with PHPMyAdmin, do you think the JOIN requires me to enforce a foreign key on the tables ?

Comment: No.  MySQL doesn't even have a real concept of foreign keys.  They're just notational IIRC and don't really have any function yet.  Regardless, you don't need foreign key definitions at all to do a join.  The join criteria can be pretty much anything... or nothing at all (for a Cartesian product).